# Why is Google Sheets or Google App Script not providing me with the same time values as what is displayed?

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets

### Context

I have an RESTful API built with Google App Script on a Google Sheet. One of the `doGet()` requests will retrieve data from one of the sheet tabs stored in a traditional column/row (database-like) fashion (structure described later). Simply, the `doGet()` will evoke another function to get the data, then it will encode that data into JSON response for the client.

#### The Data in the Sheet

This is what the data looks like on the sheet.

| DATE | LOCATION | SHIFT | NAME | START | END |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 4-1-2021 | WP | KANTOOR I | Danny | 9:00 | 17:00 |
| 4-1-2021 | BK | BAKKERIJ I | Naomi | 9:00 | 17:00 |
| 4-1-2021 | CK | KOK I | Fidel | 7:00 | 16:00 |
| ... | ... | ... | ... | ... | ... |

#### The Google App Script Function

The function iterates over the table above and gets the the row that matches the name passed into the function against the `name` in the `NAME` column.

```
function getContactSchedule(name) {
  var payload = { schedule: [] };
  var rows = scheduleSheet // schedule sheet is the .getSheetByName() for the above sheet
    .getRange(2, 1, scheduleSheet.getLastRow(), scheduleSheet.getLastColumn())
    .getValues();


  for (var i = 0, l = rows.length; i < l; i++) {
    var shift = { date: null, location: null, shift: null, name: null, start: null, end: null };
    const scheduleItem = rows[i];
    if (name != scheduleItem[3]) continue;

    shift.date = scheduleItem[0];
    shift.location = scheduleItem[1];
    shift.shift = scheduleItem[2];
    shift.name = scheduleItem[3];
    shift.start = scheduleItem[4];
    shift.end = scheduleItem[5];
    shift.index = i;

    // add to payload.
    payload.schedule.push(shift);
  }
  return payload;
}
```

### Problem

When I get the data in the table and convert it to the Object, I see different timestamps than store (other the timezone or epoch difference).

Here is some driver code:

```
function testGetContactSchedule() {
  var data = getContactSchedule('Danny')['schedule'];
  console.log(data[0]);
}
```

Output:

```
{ date: Sun Jan 03 2021 16:00:00 GMT-0700 (Mountain Standard Time),
  location: 'WP',
  shift: 'KANTOOR I',
  name: 'Danny',
  start: Sat Dec 30 1899 01:40:28 GMT-0700 (Mountain Standard Time),
  end: Sat Dec 30 1899 09:40:28 GMT-0700 (Mountain Standard Time),
  canUpdate: true,
  index: 0 }
```

The first row of the table is the same data here, just converted into the JS Object. But the time difference is unusual.

| DATE | LOCATION | SHIFT | NAME | START | END |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 4-1-2021 | WP | KANTOOR I | Danny | 9:00 | 17:00 |

### Question

Why is there this unusual difference in time? As if it adds about 40 minutes to the time stamp rather than the 00:00 that I think I'm expecting?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The reason you are receiving the date `Sat Dec 30 1899 01:40:28 GMT-0700` is because `getValues` returns an object of type date. However, this object is adapted from Sheets - `12/30/1899 0:00:00`  representing the zero mark of time for it.

Therefore, a solution for this is to use `getDisplayValues` instead of `getValues`. This will end up returning the actual values displayed in Sheets.

#### Reference

- [Apps Script Class Range - getDisplayValues()](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/range#getdisplayvalues).

Comment: This answer saves a lot of time. Thanks for pointing out the distinction between `getValues()` and `getDisplayValues()`.

Answer (score 1):

dates are always a bit complex in JS.

You can try this script, it worked for me. You can change the format of the date and also the time zone.

```
const sheet = SpreadsheetApp.openById("ZZZZZZZ");
const data = sheet.getSheetByName("XXX").getDataRange().getValues();
function getData(){
  data.forEach(dates => {
    var date = Utilities.formatDate(new Date(dates), "GMT+2", "MM/dd/yyyy");
    console.log(date);
  })
}
```

Sheet:

[image: input]

Output:

[image: output]